# Hashtag within string breaks JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, hashtag

I am trying to save a string to an external file using JavaScript. Below is what I am executing.

```
var mytext = "1111#1111"
var a = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("a"));
a.download = "My_output.html"; 
a.href = "data:text/html," + mytext; 
a.click();
```

This code works perfectly using Chrome. However with Firefox, it stops just prior to the "#". When I look at the resulting output file I see the following:

Results in Chrome look like this 
`1111#1111`

Results in Firefox look like this
`1111`

It looks to me like the hashtag is breaking something. Can anyone help me understand why the "#" in a string is causing grief in Firefox but not Chrome? I have tried wrapping the string in double quotes as well as single quotes, but it does not appear to have any effect.

Any ideas?

Comment: have you tried encodeURIComponent("#")?

Comment: Just for the record, I arrived here for a different situation but the same string breaking because of a #, I was opening a modal/popup window to show some extra information to the user, the # was being passed in the query string, I know that what I did isn't the best solution, unless, you know that other symbols aren't used... so I replaced the # for ^ and then in the popup the ^ for #... works... and is quick xD

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add URL Encoding to your string before you submit it.

```
var mytext = encodeURIComponent( "1111#1111" );
var a = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("a"));
a.download = "My_output.html"; 
a.href = "data:text/html," + mytext; 
a.click();
```

More information can be found here: [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)

EDIT: And, this is just me btw, but why would you even do data:text/html?   Just seems unnecessary.

You could just as easily submit this via Ajax (or use jQuery's $.ajax if you have that library available).  If you happen to use jQuery, then all of this might be a little easier.  Either way, hope that helps.

Comment: in response to the edit.. this is so a user can download html contents... so he can generate a html file on the fly for the user to download, for example a receipt or such without having to provide  an actual download file.

Comment: Thanks that did it. Works like a champ. Many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If I use this in firefox it comes out fine

```
var mytext = encodeURIComponent("1111#1111");
var a = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("a"));
a.download = "My_output.html"; 
a.href = "data:text/html," + mytext; 
a.click();
```

The trick is as always to encode uri components. And what you are passing along is in essense an uri component.

This way all special characters like ? # and + and % will be parsed correctly.